Two matrices satisfying three conditions
I have two unknown matrices $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times l} $ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $ and the following conditions that they need to satisfy:
$$ A^\top B= C \in \mathbb{R}^{ l \times n} , \quad  A^\top A = D\in \mathbb{R}^{ l \times l}, \quad B^\top B =E \in \mathbb{R}^{ n \times n}$$
where $ C, D, E$ are known. Are there multiple choices for $A$ and $B$ satisfying these conditions? Is there a way to construct them?

Suppose $l=m=n$. Then you have given $3n^2$ constraints but you only have $2n^2$ degrees of freedom. So the problem appears to be overspecified.

The solutions, if any, are clearly not unique. E.g. if $(A,B)$ is a pair of solutions, so is $(QA,QB)$ for any orthogonal matrix $Q$.
